# Getting Google search page like a browser in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, request, google-search

I'm coding a parser for Google Ads and I need to separate top and bottom sections.
When I get a page with Node.JS request module I get all ads with ('.ads-ad') selector. The same I get via a browser.
But in a browser I can see parent DIV element with id='taw' (for top ads) and parent DIV element with id='bottomads' (for bottom ads). But I don't see these DIV elements with request.
Is there existing simple way to get Google page like a browser?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) or [Casper JS](http://casperjs.org/). These are headless browsers which render the pages and run any javascript on the page, this ensures the the final content is the same as in your browser.